# tomcat7 connection pool error

Tags: tomcat7, connection-pooling

When I start tomcat7.0_26 on ubuntu 12/JDK7 (running on a VM/virtual box), I keep getting the following error about the DataSourceFactory in the catalina.out file in the logs directory.  Any ideas how this can be resolved?  I have copied the relevant server.xml and context.xml portions below as well.  I am able to connect to the postgres DB with the supplied username/pwd combination.

**server.xml**:

```xml
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      name="jdbc/DB"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBName"
      username="database-user"
      password="database-user-pwd"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="30000"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
      maxActive="100"
      minIdle="10"
      maxWait="10000"
      initialSize="10"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      logAbandoned="true"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
      jmxEnabled="true"
```

**context.xml**

```xml
<Context> 

   <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

  <ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                name="jdbc/DB"
                global="jdbc/DB"/>    

</Context>
```

**catalina.out**:

```
Aug 15, 2013 3:39:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1052 ms
Aug 15, 2013 3:39:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]
Aug 15, 2013 3:39:22 PM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener createMBeans
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:84)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:119)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:73)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:82)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be missing the jar file `tomcat-jdbc.jar`. It is not included by default in the standard Debian/Ubuntu package. You can download it from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ctomcat-jdbc).

Comment: I added the tomcat-jdbc jar file to the /usr/share/tomcat7/lib directory (on ubuntu).  I did the same for the postgres driver too. I would like to know if there was a better way of handling this with tomcat on ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I did it the same way.